# R caret glmnet standardize = FALSE

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet, standardized

I'm trying to use the `caret` package to play with `alpha` levels for a `glmnet` model.  The problem is that the data I'm using is all dummy variables and I don't want `glmnet` to standardize them.  Usually if I was just using `glmnet` or `cv.glmnet` on its own, I'd just add

```
standardize = FALSE
```

Is there a setting in `caret` to turn off standardize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In caret, you can feed original function arguments into `caret::train` thanks to the ellipsis `...` mechanism.

For example this code will fit a regularized regression on non standardized data

```
require(caret)
require(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)

enet <-  train(medv ~ .,
               data = BostonHousing, 
               method = "glmnet",
               standardize = FALSE)
```